# How to get around problem with org.eclipse.core.runtime referencing incorrect version of org.eclipse.equinox.common?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, equinox

I'm trying to rebuild an old eclipse feature product using the latest Eclipse version (2020-03 / 4.15.0) to support Java 11. The build itself uses JDK 1.8.

I'm getting this error below during the build:

```
    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.runtime [6]
      Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="[3.10.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
```

The problem here is that the `org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.17.100.v20200203-0917.jar` (which comes with Eclipse 4.15.0) explicitly references `org.eclipse.equinox.common` version 3.10.0. I've checked its MANIFEST.MF file to confirm. However, the `org.eclipse.equinox.common` plugin is currently at version 3.11. It comes with Equinox 3.15. Eclipse won't let me install any older Equinox version.

I tried dropping `org.eclipse.equinox.common-3.10.0.jar` (downloaded straight from mvnrepository.com) in the same location as the `org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.17.100.v20200203-0917.jar`. That didn't help at all.

Short of waiting for Eclipse to fix this "bug", what else should I try?

Note: I've read other Stackoverflow posts with a similar error. My config.ini already has org.eclipse.core.runtime@start added, and my .product file already has the start-levels cleared.

Comment: That message says it wants any version of at least 3.10.0 and less than 4.0.0, so 3.11.0 is fine - in fact that is exactly the combination that Eclipse 2020-03 itself is using (and also several of my own RCPs). Something in your build is picking up some other version.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Duh, I was so fixated on the first version number that I didn't realize `[3.10.0,4.0.0)` is a range.

Comment: Now check the log to see if org.eclipse.equinox.common has an unresolved requirement.

Comment: @nitind there is no other unresolved requirement, unfortunately. There is an older eclipse version (4.5.2) on this build server and its plugins is under the eclipse installation.  Whereas eclipse 4.15.0's plugins is located in the user directory/.p2/pool. So I'm trying to figure out if it's some how looking at 4.5.2's plugins folder, which does contain the older org.eclipse.equinox.common-3.7.0

Comment: @greg-449 any suggestion on how to troubleshoot this error further? I've ensured only `org.eclipse.equinox.common` version 3.10 and 3.11 exist on the box, yet it still complains. I've put the 3.10 and 3.11 jar files in the same locations of the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` jar file: C:\Users\zoomzoom\.p2\pool\plugins\ and C:\eclipse\eclipse4_15_0\eclipse\plugins without luck...

Comment: As I said there is something wrong with your build, since you haven't told us anything about that it is hard to help.  All these plugins should be coming from your target platform.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks, I've posted a separate question where I've included the complete PDE build log output. I'm just looking for a way to find more clues at this point. Appreciate any insights! https://stackoverflow.com/q/61459907/1371217